# Change the HTTP status code with a Google Cloud Function Promise

Tags: firebase, rest, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

My code checks if a user is authorized, if the user is, the proper code is run. If the user is not, it run `reject()` to reject the promise.

If I run the code authenticated, I get

`{"error":{"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","message":"Bad Request"}}`

I am trying to change the status code to Forbidden (code 403) which you would normally do with `res.status(403)` however since this is a promise it is different. How can I change the error code returned?

My code is as follows:

```
const cloudFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        auth.verifyIdToken(data.userId).then(function(decodedToken) {
            if(claims.admin === true) {
                // Run code if user has admin role
            }
            else {
                reject()
                // Return error code 403 because user does not have admin role
            }
        }).catch(err => reject(err)) // Return error code 401 because user is not logged in
    })
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the HTTP status for a callable function.  Callable functions essentially take over and hide the HTTP protocol for the request and response.  All you do is specify the input and output objects, and the SDKs handle everything else.

If you need to control the HTTP status of a response, you will have to use a regular HTTP type function instead.  Then you will have full control over the request and response.

Comment: I don't understand.  How will what change?

Comment: If I remove the promise and do a .then() and .catch() what will change?

Comment: I didn't recommend that you do so. Please read my answer again.  You have no control over the HTTP status code for a callable function.

Comment: `you will have to use a regular HTTP type function instead`

Comment: Read the documentation for HTTP type functions to see how they work: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events